# how to display data in html table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I have object like this:[my object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFIKb.png)

and I would like to display this data in html table.
I get all this values by this:

```
Object.entries(this.state.urls).forEach(([property, value]) => {
  console.log(value)
})
```

and now it looks like:
[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFIKb.png)

how to put all this elements to one table ?

Comment: seems not to be objects. Looks more like an array of strings.

Comment: Your question will be easier to answer if you provide 1) a code snippet of the actual input (one that I can paste into my editor - I don't mean what `console.log` prints) and 2) a code snippet of the output that you expect. Or maybe you could write a failing unit test with a correct assertion that shows what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `this.state.urls` is an array of arrays and you want to merge all the url's in each array into 1 array.

Try following

```
var urls = [].concat.apply([], this.state.urls);
```